# How can I catch mouse leave event using user32.dll

Tags: c#, mouseevent, user32

I'm using user32.dll for getting cursor position and simulating mouse click and etc.. I'm using MouseLeave event in WPF app.But I want to catch mouse leave (or mouse over) event from all windows (not only in my WPF app). Is it possbile to catch this event using user32.dll or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it like this

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool GetCursorPos(out Point lpPoint);

    void StartGettingCursorPos()
    {
        Task.Run(new Action(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                GetCursorPos(out Point point);
                Console.WriteLine($"X:{point.X}; Y:{point.Y}");
                Thread.Sleep(20);
            }
        }));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a Windows API call which allows getting mouse events even if they are not in the window:

SetCapture(hWnd)

You can combine this with a call to:

WindowFromPoint()

to get which Window the mouse is over

Comment: Could you give an example?